# Why thread still locks after synchronised method is executed?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm reading java multithreading tutorial which says thread only gives up key until it completes synchronised method, however when I run the following code (about 20 times):

```
public class SyncDemo implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sync();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void sync() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SyncDemo s = new SyncDemo();
        Thread a = new Thread(s, "a");
        Thread b = new Thread(s, "b");
        a.start();
        b.start();
    }
}
```

it only prints `a` then `b`, which I expect a mixed sequence of them because current thread will unlock every time after `sync()` is executed inside the loop? Thus giving the other thread a chance to print its name?

Comment: When I ran, I got mixed sequences of `a` and `b`.

Comment: Chances are, the first thread has finished before the second one is started.

Comment: ok that's a relief though I just tried another 20 times still gives me the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in your program that would demand a certain execution order. So the run time will schedule the threads in a way that makes most sense in the current situation. Factors that may influence the order are number of processors, load situation, ...